# aapt, ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: android, decompiling, aapt

I know there are a lot of these topics around but none seem to help in my case, nor describe it exactly.

My problem is when I run this command `./aapt d test.apk myfolder` (in mac)
I'm getting `ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found`

I tried to extract apk by changing it to jar file. After extract manifest file was there.
The only thing that I think is throwing error encryption of manifest file.
When I'm opening manifest (or any other xml drawable files) file in an editor the thing that I see is:
[image]

However when I use `aapt l -a name.apk` command, I'm able to see manifest file in terminal but has hundreds of line which is not eye friendly.

any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

manifest file is serialized and hence in non-human readable form

try to de-compile the apk via apktools.jar

{remember to install the framework-res.apk from your phone/tablet first}

Comment: Thanks Nik, I tested. Although I decompiled it successfully, manifest was clean. There was no even one character in it :(

Comment: "no even one character in it" ??? Then what does it shows.. Can u tell me that.... Paste some part it.

Comment: Obfuscator DexGuard tampers with androidManifest.xml, giving error when apk is decomplied..

Comment: I did following order: 1) I downloaded apktools.jar from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195680 2) Since it's for windows and I'm using Mac and file didn't have apktool for Mac, I downloaded it from https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool-install-macosx-r05-ibot.tar.bz2 3) Since I didn't have 'framework-res.apk' then found it from here https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/issues/detail?id=281 4) I put all of them to a folder and run this command "apktool if framework-res.apk
apktool d semcmusic.apk" based on what first link says.

Comment: After decompile I have manifest file and smali folder (no res) folder. I tested above order on other apk file and I could see manifest, smalifolder, res folder and apktool.yml (which i don't know what it is) but I could see content of manifest file clearly. So have no idea why apktool was not able to decompile first apk file?!